# Julia: elegant way to identify 2 strings

Tags: string, julia

I wonder there is an elegant way to indentify 2 strings by Julia.
I mean,there are 2 strings, for example

```
   1.I think this is good
   2.This is good, I think
```

Both are the same meaning of course, but the words order are different.
I am not good at such like procedure. How do you do it usually? Do you set all words into array variables then compare the each elements existents?
I believe there is a marvelous way in Julia.

Thanks any advance.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a step by step example:

```
julia> using StatsBase

julia> strs = ["I think this is good", "This is good, I think"] # initial vector of strings
2-element Vector{String}:
 "I think this is good"
 "This is good, I think"

julia> split.(strs, r"\W", keepempty=false) # split them by non-word characters
2-element Vector{Vector{SubString{String}}}:
 ["I", "think", "this", "is", "good"]
 ["This", "is", "good", "I", "think"]

julia> map(x -> lowercase.(x), (split.(strs, r"\W", keepempty=false))) # lowercase all words
2-element Vector{Vector{String}}:
 ["i", "think", "this", "is", "good"]
 ["this", "is", "good", "i", "think"]

julia> sort.(map(x -> lowercase.(x), (split.(strs, r"\W", keepempty=false)))) # sort each entry
2-element Vector{Vector{String}}:
 ["good", "i", "is", "think", "this"]
 ["good", "i", "is", "think", "this"]

julia> countmap(sort.(map(x -> lowercase.(x), (split.(strs, r"\W", keepempty=false))))) # finally count the number of duplicates, you need StatsBaes for this
Dict{Vector{String}, Int64} with 1 entry:
  ["good", "i", "is", "think", "this"] => 2
```

Comment: Instead of `countmap`, `allequal(...sorted vectors...)` also works

Comment: yes, but I would prefer `countmap` if there were e.g. 100 strings and OP wanted to find how many of them are unique and how many duplicates are of each string.

Comment: With `countmap` there is the problem of repeated words which would drive counts higher. Maybe a Hamming-like distance measure would be good.

Comment: Indeed, in general the question how to measure similarity needs to be defined by OP for his specific use case (e.g. I lowercased the words, but maybe OP does not want it).

Comment: Thank you as always, Dr. Kaminski. Ah,just as I thought, it uses array, but it wors fine and the speed is very satisfactory in comparing with 50 sentences. Thank you again.

Answer (score -1):

```
string1 = "I think this is good"
string2 = "This is good, I think"

//Step 1 (remove blank spaces)
string1 = strip(string1)
string2 = strip(string2)

//Step 2 (splitting the strings into individual words, creating a vector of words for each string)
words1 = split(string1)
words2 = split(string2)

//Step 3 (sort the word vectors in alphabetical order)
sorted_words1 = sort(words1)
sorted_words2 = sort(words2)

//Step 4
if sorted_words1 == sorted_words2
    println("Same")
else
    println("Different")
end
```